# Establishing a recursive regression

Tags: r, recursion, regression

I want to build a recursive regression. The regression is to be performed for each country with each product separately. Therefore I used the nest-function. Y is the demand and X1 to X3 are independent variables. The time period is 40 years. I used the simple regression first and this was successful. But there I only get the result after 40 years. Therefore I want to build a recursive regression, which takes the latest value after the first 9 years (t0 to 9 years) and performs a regression for t0 to 10 years, t0 to 11 years, t0 to 12 years ... etc.

My result for the simple regression is:

```
# reproducible data 
df <- tibble(Country = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each = 200)),
             YEAR = rep(rep(c(1971:2010), each = 1), 20),
             Product = rep(c(1:20), each = 40),
             Y = rnorm(800),
             X1 = rnorm(800),
             X2 = rnorm(800),
             X3 = rnorm(800))


# nest data
data_nest <- df %>%
    group_by(Country, Product) %>%
    nest() %>%
    ungroup()


lm.function <- function(x, formula) {
    lm(formula = formula,
       data = x)
}

# using normal regression
data_lm <- data_nest %>%
    mutate(lm = map(
        .x = data,
        .f = lm.function,
        formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3
    ))
```

**How do I change my lm.function so that I can perform the desired recursive regression?**

My idea does not work - I tried a a lot of Package like Roll or Rollreg, but nothing works

```
lm.function = function(x, formula) {
    roll_regres(formula = demand ~ sum_cases + weekly_hits + sum_deaths,
       data = x, width = 9L)
}
```

The problem is my "nested" Data (List) because it works without it, but in this case I don't get my desired outcome.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you! :)

Comment: is this really recursion or its a loop? ie perform regression on the data from t0, to t0+9, then perform another regression from t0:t10 then perform on t0:t11 etc. This is loop

Comment: I think you're right - actually I was thinking about using a loop but the problem is that I don't know how to separate the different cases in a loop.

Comment: You just need an index and a stoping criteria. No need of case.